# Adding a reference from a native C++ DLL to a C++/CLI DLL in VS2010 doesn't add the import library to the linker command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I have a somewhat odd problem that I don't seem to be able to get to the bottom of. We have a mostly unmanaged C++ application that's been around for a while and thus has been built using lots of different versions of Visual Studio, with it being updated to the current version of Visual Studio on a regular basis.

I've now run into the following issue:

- In VS2010 I've added two new projects to the existing solution. Both new projects are DLLs, one built in plain unmanaged C++, the built using a mix of C++ and C++/CLI and is thus built with CLR support (/clr). The second C++/CLI DLL should be used by several other components of the system
- Using Properties -> Common Properties -> Framework and References, I add the two new DLLs as a dependency to a third DLL. The third DLL is doesn't know anything about .NET and is implemented in pure native, unmanaged C++. The new DLLs show up correctly in the dependency settings and the new references work in the sense that the build order of the solution is affected (correct), but for some reason, only the import library for the plain native C++ DLL is added to the linker command line for DLL that references both libraries. The second, mixed library generates an import library, but VS2010 doesn't add the import library to the linker command line which predictably results in several unresolved external symbols.
- The one setting that appears to trigger this behaviour is building the DLL with Common Language runtime support as all the other settings of the libraries are identical.

I currently have a workaround for this issue - I simply add the import library as a manual dependency - but I was wondering if someone else has encountered this problem and if there is a way to get make this feature work as expected without the workaround?

Comment: Is the third library (the one referencing the two new projects) a managed or unmanaged dll?

Comment: @Matt - the library referencing the two new projects is unmanaged native legacy code that doesn't know anything about the CLR. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit the question to make that clearer.